# Need to access value in SimpleXML object

Tags: php, simplexml

This should be really easy, but I'm just not seeing how to do it. I just need to access the value of the element document-id.

```
print_r($http_result_simplexml);
```

gives...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [document-id] => 1234 )
```

I need to get this document ID number, but I'm not getting how to do it. I tried $http_result_simplexml['document-id'], but it doesn't work. What I'm understading is that 'document-id' is the element, and '1234' is the value of the element. Another method I've come across is $http_result_simplexml->element_name, but obvisouly, the minus sign in 'document-id' won't work there.. I'm sure this is something absurdly simple..

(please correct me if that's not called the "element")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the element you are looking for:
`$document_id = $http_result_simplexml->{'document-id'}`

`$document_id` will also be a `SimpleXMLObject`! so you have to cast the value, using either:
`$document_id = (string)$document_id;` or `$document_id = (int)$document_id;`
depending on whether you want a string or integer.

`print_r($document_id); //should give the result you want now`

Comment: I don't quite understand. do you mean, I need to cast like this? (string)$http_result_simplexml['document-id']? This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user796837 Nor should it. You have a SimpleXMLObject returned. The keyword is "object", not an "array". You need to access elements with the proper notation. Show your code for specific help please.

Comment: thank you. I understand now. The key is to realize that it's an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the `__toString()`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

```
$element = $http_result_simplexml->{'document-id'}->__toString();
```

should work also.